# Extract the filename and folder name into 2 columns of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, csv, directory, filenames

I have a folder named 'Device 1 - Bin 4 - LongTube' and inside that there are 8 csv files. I'm going to read the data in each file and then store that in a dataframe. Apart from the columns in the data files I also want to include the filename of each file in a seperate column in the same dataframe. I also want to include the folder name (Device 1 - Bin 4 - LongTube) as a separate column in the dataframe. How can I do this in R?

I used the below code to start with but it didn't generate the 2 columns for filename and the foldername separately.

```
## Specify the csv file folder
mydir = "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Data/Device 1 - Bin 4 - LongTube"
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir,full.names=TRUE)

# create an empty list to store the dataframes
datalist <- list()

for (file in myfiles)
{
  ## Importing the data file 
  df <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE)
  
  ## Extract the filename
  df$filename <- myfiles
  
  # add the dataframe to the list
  datalist[[file]] <- df

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Data prep:

```r
dir.create("subdir")
write.csv(mtcars[1:3,], "subdir/mt.csv", row.names=FALSE)
write.csv(iris[1:3,], "subdir/iris.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Retrieve file list:

```r
myfiles <- list.files("subdir", pattern = "csv$", full.names = TRUE)
myfiles
# [1] "subdir/iris.csv" "subdir/mt.csv"
```

Read in files into a list of frames:

```r
datalist <- lapply(setNames(nm = myfiles), read.csv)
datalist
# $`subdir/iris.csv`
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# $`subdir/mt.csv`
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
```

Add dir and filenames:

```r
datalist <- Map(function(x, fn) transform(x, filename=basename(fn), dir=dirname(fn)), datalist, myfiles)
datalist
# $`subdir/iris.csv`
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species filename    dir
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa iris.csv subdir
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa iris.csv subdir
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa iris.csv subdir
# $`subdir/mt.csv`
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb filename    dir
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   mt.csv subdir
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   mt.csv subdir
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   mt.csv subdir
```